# Recording RTP stream and subsequent playback

Tags: rtp, rtcp

I am looking for some open source library written in C that dumps RTP packets (RTCP packets are available too) in a file so that that file can be then played. For simplicity, to get a hang of the issues, I want to just record audio (e.g. opus encoded).
If there is no such library, is there any literature to guide me on how to handle this?

I think there will be issues involved but not as many as in live P2P RTP interaction, as in a webRTC call.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at GStreamer https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org
Or try ffmpeg https://www.ffmpeg.org

Comment: Do you know of any lightweight option? For example, I just want to take rtp packets from a media server which gets input from a webrtc termination and record it as well as forward it. The forwarding part I get but I am not familiar with the recording (saving part) given that there are timing issues with the rtp packets. Do these recorders also need rtcp packets?